# htaccess mod_rewrite part of url to GET variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some URLs like these:

- `http://plutov.by/post/cubique_zf_jquery`
- `http://plutov.by/post/mysql_useful_queries`

How can I with help of Apache mod_rewrite open the next pages?

- `http://plutov.by/post/main?title=cubique_zf_jquery`
- `http://plutov.by/post/main?title=mysql_useful_queries`

Also, will be this new rewrite rule work with "one entry point rewriting"?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the new rewrite rule work with "one entry point rewriting", have your `rewriteRules` like this:

The `QSA` flag is *mandatory* as you are adding a new query string.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(post)/([\w\d\-]+)/?$ $1/main?title=$2 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

- [Flag `QSA` <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).
- `!-l` checks that the requested URI is not a symbolic ink.

Comment: QSA flag is not mandatory if you don't care about the existing query strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ post/main?title=$1 [L]
```

You should keep this rule BEFORE one entry point rewriting rules. If rule will trigger then rewrite rule lookup will be finished (since [L] option specified)

Some modification of paths may be required if you want to use these rules in VirtualHost context